# Make ExtJS button's ariaLabel content to be dynamic

Tags: extjs

Is it possible to make the button's aria-label text dynamic in ExtJS? For example, I want the button's aria-label to be dynamically changing depending on the application's context.

```
Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
    title: 'test title',
    viewModel: {
        data: {
            firstname: undefined
        }
    },
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'textField',
            fieldLabel: 'firstname'
        },

        {
            xtype: 'button',
            ariaLabel: 'open modal',// make this text dynamic
            text: 'SignIn',
            bind: {
                text: '{firstname}'
            }
        }
    ],
});
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot bind aria-label or set it after rendering time.

Read [ariaAttributes](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.2.0/modern/Ext.Container.html#cfg-ariaAttributes) which says

> **Note** that this config is only meaningful at the Component rendering time, and setting it after that will do nothing.

You can only re-set them by recreating the component.

Comment: That's really helpful thank you @Dinkheller

Comment: @imagine24. If this is the correct answer you might want to check it as 'answered'